# How to solve the equation $\sqrt{x^{2}-x+2}+\sqrt{2x^{2}+2x+3}=\sqrt{2x^{2}-1}+\sqrt{x^{2}-3x-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve in real numbers the equation $$\sqrt{x^{2}-x+2}+\sqrt{2x^{2}+2x+3}=\sqrt{2x^{2}-1}+\sqrt{x^{2}-3x-2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the equation as 
$$\sqrt{x^{2}-x+2}-\sqrt{x^{2}-3x-2}=\sqrt{2x^{2}-1}-\sqrt{2x^{2}+2x+3}.\tag{$1$}$$
On each side, do the usual trick of multiplying "tops" and "bottoms" by the conjugates. A semi-miracle happens. We get
$$\frac{2x+4}{ \sqrt{x^{2}-x+2}+\sqrt{x^{2}-3x-2} }=\frac{-(2x+4)}{\sqrt{2x^{2}-1}+\sqrt{2x^{2}+2x+3}}.\tag{$2$}$$

After making  note to check about $x=-2$ later, cancel the $2x+4$ terms on top of $(2)$, then flip both sides of $(2)$ over.

We get an equation that marries very nicely with $(1)$, and two of the square roots are gone.  We get an equation of shape $\sqrt{A}=-\sqrt{B}$. So it comes down to checking $x=-2$ (works).

**Remark:** The trick could have been used directly with the equation as given. However, in more complicated cases, reduction of degree is useful.

Comment: Since OP requires the equation to be solved over the reals, is it correct to say that there is only one solution?

Comment: Yes, after we do the manipulation, we get $\sqrt{A}=-\sqrt{B}$!

Comment: You are welcome. The trick I used, and variants, come up modestly often in "sum of distances" problems. Note that you can save a little time by using the same trick on the equation as given.